# String length difference between ruby 1.8 and 1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a website thats running on ruby 1.8.7 . I have a validation on an incoming post that checks to make sure that we allow  upto max of 12000 characters. The spaces are counted as characters and tab and carriage returns are stripped off before the post is subjected to the validation.

Here is the post that is subjected to validation http://pastie.org/5047582

In ruby 1.9 the string length shows up as 11909 which is correct. But when I check the length on ruby 1.8.7 is turns out to be 12044.

I used codepad.org to run this ruby code which gives me http://codepad.org/OxgSuKGZ ( which outputs the length as 12044 which is wrong) but when i run this same code in the console at codeacademy.org the string length is 11909.

Can anybody explain me why this is happening ???

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a Unicode issue. The string you are using contains characters outside the ASCII range, and the UTF-8 encoding that is frequently used encodes those as 2 (or more) bytes.

Ruby 1.8 did not handle Unicode properly, and `length` simply gives the number of **bytes** in the string, which results in fun stuff like:

```
"ą".length
=> 2
```

Ruby 1.9 has better Unicode handling. This includes `length` returning the actual number of **characters** in the string, as long as Ruby knows the encoding:

```
"ä".length
=> 1
```

One possible workaround in Ruby 1.8 is using regular expressions, which can be made Unicode aware:

```
"ą".scan(/./mu).size
=> 1
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.  But if you carefully check the string in the pastie you'll see that there are no unicode characters in the post.Do you have the list of characters  which are counted on bytes rather than characters ??

Comment: There are - the quotes for example are not the `"` character, but separate left quote and right quote characters, which are not ASCII.

Comment: well Thanks again. I'll use that a fix

Comment: Awesome regex flags you've got there :)